# Is there a way to measure the dimensions of a room using sceneform?

Tags: java, android, arcore, sceneform

I'm working on an interior design project using the sceneform arcore API. Please I want to know if there is a way I can get the dimensions of the room in which the furniture will be placed.
Or if there is way I can probably add google's measure app or any other measuring application to my application

Answer (score 0):

A plausible solution would be to place a `Node` (if you want it to be visible) or `Anchor` (if you want it to be invisible) at the corners of the room and get their world position. The distance between the nodes can then be calculated using their (x,y,z) values.
I have used a similar concept to calculate the distance between two nodes before, although I didn't have the need to have them more then ~3 metres from each other, so I can't vouch for their accuracy, but it's worth a shot.

(Note: 1f in Vector3 translation corresponds to 1 metre in real life)

Comment: Hi, mark the answer as correct if it works(or feel free to add your own answer if you found a better alternative), cheers.